# why is axios.get not returning a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

In the following code, why is the last `axios.get(  url.toString())` not returning a promise and instead returning undefined ? How  can we handle this ?

```
function getCommentersEmailIds( username ) {
    let foundUserId = undefined;
    //first get user id of username
    axios.get( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?username='+username )
    .then(function( response ) {
        var foundUser = response.data.find(u=>u.username === username);
        return foundUser.id;
    })
    .then(function( userId ) {
        let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+ userId.toString() +'/posts';
        return axios.get( url.toString());
    })
    .then(function( posts ) {
        //get id of the first post
        let postId = posts.data[0].id;
        let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?' + postId.toString();
        return axios.get(  url.toString());
    })
    .catch(function( error ) {
        console.log( error.message );
    });
}

var promiseForComments = getCommentersEmailIds('Bret');
promiseForComments.then(function( comments ) {
   comments.data.array.forEach(comment => {
       console.log(comment.email);
   }); 
})
.catch(function( error ) {
    console.log( error.message );
});
```

Comment: As the answers below indicate, it looks like the problem is that your `getCommentersEmailIds` has no `return`. There is an additional bug here, in that if any error occurs in the various parts of `getCommentersEmailIds`, the `catch` will catch it and return a promise for `undefined`. This `undefined` would be received in the `then` below and cause a further error when you try to dereference `comments.data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are missing a `return` statement in `getCommentersEmailIds()` rather than an issue specific to the second call to `axios.get`:

```
function getCommentersEmailIds( username ) {
    let foundUserId = undefined;

    //Update: add return before axio.get
    return axios.get( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?username='+username )
    .then(function( response ) {
        var foundUser = response.data.find(u=>u.username === username);
        return foundUser.id;
    })
    .then(function( userId ) {
        let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+ userId.toString() +'/posts';
        return axios.get( url.toString());
    })
    .then(function( posts ) {
        //get id of the first post
        let postId = posts.data[0].id;
        let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?' + postId.toString();
        return axios.get(  url.toString());
    })
    .catch(function( error ) {
        console.log( error.message );
    });
}
```

By returning the promise of `axios.get()` from `getCommentersEmailIds()`, the subsequent chaining (that leads to `forEach()` iteration over `comments.data.array`) should be executed as expected.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you are not returning anything from function getCommentersEmailIds

make it

```
function getCommentersEmailIds( username ) {
    let foundUserId = undefined;
    //first get user id of username
   return axios.get(...).then(...).then()...
```

}